# Total Least squares regression without intercept, with R

Tags: r, regression, principal-components

I need to calculate the beta of a regression between two prices with:

1. No intercept
2. Using Total Least Squares estimate

In R there is the function `prcomp` to perform it.
After it, how can I extract the beta?

the code is

```
`library(quantmod)
# how to get closes
getCloses <- function(sym) {
    ohlc <- getSymbols(sym, from="2009-01-01", to="2011-01-01",
                       auto.assign=FALSE, return.class="zoo")
    Cl(ohlc)}
# how to import data (2 assets)
closes <- merge(IWM=getCloses("IWM"),
            VXZ=getCloses("VXZ"), all=FALSE)
# function for hedging ratio
tlsHedgeRatio <- function(p, q) {
    r <- princomp( ~ p + q+0)
    r$loadings[1,1] / r$loadings[2,1]
}
# get the hedging ratio
with(closes, {
    cat("TLS for VXZ vs. IWM =", tlsHedgeRatio(VXZ,IWM), "\n")
})`
```

In the code show how to perform TLS regression with intercept. I trying to perform the same without intercept.
While with `lm` function, adding `+0` allow to perform regression without intercept, how could I do the same with `prcomp`function?

Comment: This question could be improved by providing a [reproducibe example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample (fake) input data so we see how your data is shaped. I don't see why you would use `prcomp` rather than the standard `lm` function for fitting a regression.

Comment: If you are interested in applying TLS with prcomp, read [**this**](http://quanttrader.info/public/betterHedgeRatios.pdf).

Comment: @MrFlick TLS is sometimes preferred because it does not assume all the errors are coming from what you specify as the independent variable. This has an affect on the slope and intercept of the linear model: https://statpad.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/ols_eiv_plots.jpeg

Comment: Thanks @Stu somehow i missed the "total" part.

Comment: @user3641445 have you tried before asking? Which particular point are you missing? Please share your code.

Comment: Code added in the question. It is an example given by Paul Teetor.

Answer (score 0):

If R is the matrix that contains the data

```
pcaresult <- prcomp(R)
eigenVect <- pcaresult$rotation
eigenVal <- (pcaresult$sdev)^2
coeff1 = as.numeric(coeff$eigenvectors[,"PC2"][1])
coeff2 = -as.numeric(coeff$eigenvectors[,"PC2"][2])
ratio = coeff2/coeff1
```

you can also check the function `?MethComp::Deming` (in package `MethComp`) which gives similar result.

Comment: now I understood how to extract coefficients, but I didn't understand yet how to do it without intercept (y=beta*x)